# tax vat field unique like email magento registration page

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to make the taxvat field of magento registration but i am kind of confused how do i will make it unique so everyone need to add a unique vat number . 
here i found the email thing in accountcontroller.php

```
 catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
                $session->setEscapeMessages(false);
            }
            else {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $session->addError($message);
        }
```

Now i would like to have my taxvat field also unique like email address how i suppose to do it anybody have the code for it ?

Comment: Create a code by yourself pls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Magento database at hand to check this out, but you can probably set this attribute to "unique". 
Have a look into your customer_attribute table (or eav_attributes, I'm not sure)

If this is working, switch back to normal & create a setup file which will update the attribute in your module setup directory.

Comment: well i have already tried but i can't enable the unique field. Because it is disabled to make changes. I can change name and others but the unique value is locked so can't change it.